# Search a file for a string in multiple directories

Tags: command-line, text-processing, files, grep, find

Can someone please help me with a command to search a file for a string in multiple directories? I am searching for the VIP in `httpd.conf` in multiple httpd instances.

I am using:

```
find ./ -name "httpd.conf" | xargs grep 10.22.0.141 cut -d: -f3- | cut -d ' ' -f4 | sort | uniq -c
```

But its not working.

```
charl@rom11-TEST $ ls -latr
total 124
...
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 9 13:41 bofac-Wrapper
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 29 2014 bofac-admin
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 29 2014 bofac-chas-test
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 29 2014 bofac-chasdps-test
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 Oct 10 14:09 bofac-vpn-chas-test
...
```

Basically the `httpd` instances are highlighted but I would ideally run the command against the entire directory.

Comment: Can you add an example how that vip (the whole region) in the `httpd.conf` files looks like?

Comment: Listen 10.22.0.41:90004
                                                                                                                               Listen 10.22.0.41:80004

Comment: In `xargs grep 10.22.0.141 cut -d: -f3-`, you seem to be missing a pipe character.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -r --include "httpd.conf" "10.22.0.141" . | cut -d: -f3- |\
cut -d ' ' -f4 | sort | uniq -c
```